# Retrieve value of a select "on change" generated in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently generating some html (select) via javascript code and i would like to retrieve the value of my select to display another div depending on the value

```
$("#" + id).append(
'<select id="dropDownRole" form="dropDownRole">' +
'<option value="none">---</option>' +
'<option value="root">root</option>' +
'<option value="customer">customer</option>' +
'</select>' +
'<br>'+
```

this code is inside a javascript function and i want to catch the change of the dropDownRole to use it

I know that there are some topics about it but none with html created via javascript and if i should change it

Thanks and fly safe o/

Answer (score 1):

You have to bind an event to this new element using **[event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data)** like this,

```
$("#" + id).on('change', '#dropDownRole', function(){
    // do your stuff here.
});
```

**Delegated events** have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers.

Comment: If the above solution helped to solve your problem then you can accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this this will help you, you need to use onchange event to get the value of your select on change

```js
var id = "div1"
$("#" + id).append(
  '<select id="dropDownRole">' +
  '<option value="none">---</option>' +
  '<option value="root">root</option>' +
  '<option value="customer">customer</option>' +
  '</select>' +
  '<br>');
$("#" + id).on('change', '#dropDownRole', function() {
  $("#div2").text($('#dropDownRole').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```